# Javascript- Uncaught ReferenceError is not defined form validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Someone please help, i have no clue whats going on, I've done alot of research. I'm trying to do a form validation using `onblur`, so when I click off the screen, the `validateName()` function runs and does what I want. But instead all i get is `validateName()` is not defined, or `validateName().value` is not defined. I would really appreciate suggestions in this regard.

- Also when im linking a java script file with this code to this php file it is not working, probably same issue though. 
  -
- Full error message Uncaught ReferenceError: validateName is not defined
  at HTMLInputElement.onblur (account.php?fName=asas:52)
  onblur @ account.php?fName=asas:52

  Capstone Website | Title Undetermined

  ```
  <link rel="icon" href="images/hammerFavicon.ico" type="image/gif">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom/siteStyle.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascipt" src="js/main.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascipt" language="javascript">
      function validateName(fName) {
          var fName = form.fName.value;
          alert("fName");
      }
  </script>
  ```

  ```
      <p class="lead">Account Details</p>

      <form>
          <!---- First name and Last name --->
          <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col">
                  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                  <input type="text" onblur="validateName()" name="fName" id="fName" class="form-control"
                         placeholder="First name"/>
              </div>

              <div class="col">
                  <label for="firstName">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required maxlength="50"/>
              </div>
          </div>

          <br>
          <!---- Email --->
          <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                  <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email" required
                         maxlength="254"/>

              </div>
              <!---- Password --->
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                  <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password"/>

              </div>
          </div>
          <!---- Address --->
          <div class="form-group">

              <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St" required
                     maxlength="100"/>

          </div>
          <!---- Address 2 --->
          <div class="form-group">

              <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor"
                     required maxlength="100"/>

          </div>
          <!---- City--->
          <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                  <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" required maxlength="100"/>

              </div>
              <!---- State --->
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                  <label for="inputState">State</label>
                  <select id="inputState" class="form-control" required>
                      <option selected>Choose...</option>
                      <option>...</option>

                  </select>
              </div>
              <!---- Zip code --->
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">

                  <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" required maxlength="12"/>

              </div>
          </div>
          <!---- Button --->
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Update</button>
      </form>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: TYPO: `type="text/javascipt"` That prevents the script from running.... You have other issues in the code too such as `form` not being declared.

Comment: You need to pass your onblur method without calling it, like on `onblur="validateName"`

Comment: on the type="text/javascript",okay it should be erased. Thanks i see what your saying. IDK why i see alot of places that and language = javascript. Do you happen to know when you are suppose to do that and why?                                                                                                         PS- Thanks so much for your fast reply! first time trying this out omg why haven't i submitted questions before lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using like following because your approach is not effective. Your function expecting parameter but when you calling on `onblur` you not sending anything. Also when you trying to get value `form.fName.value` it will not work like this way.

```
function validateName(fName) {
    var fName = fName.value;
    alert(fName);
}

<input type="text" onblur="validateName(this)" name="fName" id="fName" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"/>
```

Also correct the type here: `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH. I was trying to figure this out all day lol. IDK why they sometimes ask for the type=text/javascript. I guess when it is loading from another online source??